# Selecting the Default value of an oracle column in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am trying to extract an oracle column default value from user_tab_columns, using .Net.
It's data type is long, and when I read it using IDataReader i get an empty string. How do I get it's data?

select column_name,data_default from user_tab_columns where column_name='XXX'

Answer (score 1):

The LONG datatype has a lot of restrictions on its usage.  One way to work around it would be to build a stored function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION column_default
   ( p_table VARCHAR2
   , p_column
   ) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    l_retval LONG;
BEGIN
    SELECT data_default
    INTO   l_retval
    FROM   user_tab_columns
    WHERE  table_name = p_table
    AND    column_name = p_column;

    RETURN l_retval;
END;
```

Now call that function from .Net rather than performing the query directly.

Comment: I need something that would work within an sql statement, as I do not have permission to create functions in that schema.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ODP.NET Drivers

try this

```
    OracleCommand dbCommand = new OracleCommand();
    dbCommand.InitialLONGFetchSize = 1000;
```

The InitialLONGFetchSize limits the data len in field of LONG type

it works for me;

Comment: Will look into that as soon as I can find the time again, thanks

Comment: Use `dbCommand.InitialLONGFetchSize = -1` to read the entire column regardless of size, see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featData.htm#i1007197